# Chinese radio programming software identification [ YIN TAI YT-3288 ]

Tags: software, equipment-troubleshooting, radio-programming

recently I purchased a super cheap Chinese radio to experiment with.

[image]

I would like to know if anyone knows what software to use to program this radio or if not... Is there a way I can find out by using some sort of protocol finder software etc. ?

Some details are:

The radio is supposedly the: `YIN TAI YT-3288`

The radio came with a UHF antenna.

The radio arrived pre programmed with the FTA frequencies 436.000 increasing as the channels go up to 16.

The radio is quite large and is Analog with 16 channels.

---

This radio claims to output 25W... somehow I doubt that even though the transistor can supply that.

[image]

---

FRONT OF THE PCB WITH MIC

[image]

---

BACK OF PCB

The white square covers an:

H09017 JC1925
PNP SILICON EPITAXIAL
TRANSISTOR

[image]

Comment: It's not listed [here](https://chirp.danplanet.com/projects/chirp/wiki/Supported_Radios), so apparently CHIRP will not work. I suggest that you try and contact Dan there.

Comment: @MikeWaters Please don't contact Dan directly. The [official stance on "my radio is unsupported, what do I do"](https://chirp.danplanet.com/projects/chirp/wiki/FAQ#How-can-I-get-my-radio-supported-by-CHIRP) is "Ok, we have [literal 100s of radios that people have requested](https://chirp.danplanet.com/projects/chirp/issues?query_id=15) {699 as of writing this comment.}. Unless you can help things yourself ([or as a vendor bribe someone to do it](https://chirp.danplanet.com/projects/chirp/wiki/InformationForVendors) for you), well, you're free to add another one to the list. Good luck!".

Comment: I chuckled when I read "power 25W". That's pure comedy gold, especially for a device whose lithium battery doesn't even have a thermal sensor contact :D

Comment: I think Jonas might have already done the right thing, https://chirp.danplanet.com/issues/11097

Comment: Excuse my stupid question, Jonas, but what indication do you have that this radio is programmable?

Comment: @MarcusMüller None really. just that the led blinks when I attempt to use `Wouxun` `KG-816` and `KG-818` all other attempts to program have no LED activity. Also when I attempted to program via `KYD` `IP-620` it failed with the error containing the word `iUHOUXUN` and that pointed me to try out the `Wouxun` vendors. Still it may just be keying for an external mic I just don't know 100% so maybe the guys @ Chirp can help confirm.

Comment: @MikeWaters Thanks for your reply. I did open a `New Model` issue on `CHIRP`.

Comment: Also The manual says can be changed with software a few times... but there is no mention of what software and no CD. The connector is the Kenwood style like the Baofeng UV5R